# ng-repeat-start with ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Just simple example.

My array:

```
$scope.arr = [
    {lab1: 'a1', lab2: 'a2', lab3: 'a3', val1: 'av1', val2: 'av2', val3: 'av3'},
    {lab1: 'b1', lab2: 'b2', lab3: 'b3', val1: 'bv1', val2: 'bv2', val3: 'bv3'},
    {lab1: 'c1', lab2: 'c2', lab3: 'c3', val1: 'cv1', val2: 'cv2', val3: 'cv3'},
    {lab1: 'd1', lab2: 'd2', lab3: 'd3', val1: 'dv1', val2: 'dv2', val3: 'dv3'},
    {lab1: 'e1', lab2: 'e2', lab3: 'e3', val1: 'ev1', val2: 'ev2', val3: 'ev3'},
];
```

My html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title1</th>
        <th ng-repeat-start="item in arr" ng-hide="item.val1 == 'cv1'">{{item.lab1}}</th>
        <th>{{item.lab2}}</th>
        <th ng-repeat-end>{{item.lab3}}</th>
        <th>Title2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Val1</td>
        <td ng-repeat-start="item in arr" ng-hide="item.val1 == 'cv1'">{{item.val1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.val2}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat-end>{{item.val3}}</td>
        <td>Val2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Expected table:

Title1 | a1 | a2 | a3 | b1 | b2 | b3 | d1 | d2 | d3 | e1 | e2 | e3 | Title2

Val1| av1 | av2 | av3 | bv1 | bv2 | bv3 | dv1 | dv2 | dv3 | ev1 | ev2 | ev3 | Val2

Real table:

Title1 | a1 | a2 | a3 | b1 | b2 | b3 ***| c2 | c3 |*** d1 | d2 | d3 | e1 | e2 | e3 | Title2

Val1| av1 | av2 | av3 | bv1 | bv2 | bv3 ***| cv2 | cv3 |*** dv1 | dv2 | dv3 | ev1 | ev2 | ev3 | Val2

So how can i apply ng-hide or other directives on all *ng-repeat-start end* blocks?
And no - i cant wrap it and use ng-repeat, no - i dont want use a filter...

Comment: Do you have only `0` and `1` for `val`?

Comment: No - it is just a simple example, i have many values and i must calculate expression by complicated formulas.

Answer (score 0):

So the only thing i found is to add ng-hide to all blocks in repeat:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title1</th>
        <th ng-repeat-start="item in arr" ng-hide="item.val1 == 'cv1'">{{item.lab1}}</th>
        <th ng-hide="item.val1 == 'cv1'">{{item.lab2}}</th>
        <th ng-repeat-end ng-hide="item.val1 == 'cv1'">{{item.lab3}}</th>
        <th>Title2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Val1</td>
        <td ng-repeat-start="item in arr" ng-hide="item.val1 == 'cv1'">{{item.val1}}</td>
        <td ng-hide="item.val1 == 'cv1'">{{item.val2}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat-end ng-hide="item.val1 == 'cv1'">{{item.val3}}</td>
        <td>Val2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it is very ugly, because it is code duplication, and can be used only for not so many repeated blocks..

Just will waiting better answer some time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to use ng-repeat-start? It works with just one ng-repeat:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in arr" ng-hide="item.val == 0">{{item.lab}}{{item.val}}</div>
```

Comment: Because I use it with table rows, and i can't wrap it. I wrote it in my question

Comment: What do you mean, you 'use it with table rows'? can you provide an example/fiddle?

Comment: I must repeat group of tr tags, and i can't wrap it in any tag, if it not clear I will provide code sample in 40 min when I came in office)

Comment: so i edited my question, look it and you will see that i cant use just ng-repeat